# How to open .bat file in new tab instead of new window in the new Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

With the new Windows Terminal (WT), it has a lot of potential being the best terminal on Windows. By modifying the registry for `.bat` to be opened with WT,

```
ftype batfile="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" -d . -p "Command Prompt" "%1" %*
```

it could execute the script on WT. But it has one issue, where executing another `.bat` file will open another WT window. I would like open the new `.bat` in new tab, is it possible? From [Microsoft's doc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-9-release/), new tab could be opened by,

```
wt -d . ; new-tab -d C:\ pwsh.exe
```

but how do I set it to the registry? The code below doesn't seems to work:

```
ftype batfile="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" -d . new-tab -p "Command Prompt" "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the ; in the command?

Edit:  Sorry not to be clear.  You dropped the ; from your working example when entering it in the registry.

```
ftype batfile="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" -d . ; new-tab -p "Command Prompt" "%1" %*
```

Comment: Like how exactly? And I suppose that's more of a question than an answer..